# CakePHP Membership Framework - Convert to Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I would like to know if there is a simple way to convert an existing membership framework from CakePHP to Wordpress. I am fine doing this through a plugin or hiring someone to hard code it - I just was not sure of the process.

Thanks!

Comment: Cake is a framework and Wordpress is a blogging platform CMS, they're not really the same, the "plugin" you're after would need to totally rewrite your application. Sidenote: this isn't a place to hire developers

Comment: It sounds like it would be a lateral move to migrate a membership app to wordpress. Both Wordpress and cakephp can be deemed frameworks in their own right. Both are MVC however, Wordpress and cakephp are very different when it comes to actually writing logic for an app. You might (and that is a big might) be able to shave some time off the new development of your wordpress site by treating your cakephp app as an API but it simply wouldn't be as flexible in future development. Unfortunately, I think you are stuck rebuilding in Wordpress, not migrating.

Comment: Tim, what about keeping both frameworks and then migrating back and forth between the two on the front end?  Is this an option?

Comment: If you are saying you would like some of your pages to be in wordpress and the membership pages to remain in cake then yes. You can do this and it would look almost seamless to your users since cake and wordpress allow full control over the template design and structure of your views. I have done this before when I wanted the SEO benefits of wordpress and it's plugins and the rapid development approach and flexibility of a cake app. Simply install wordpress in your webroot of your cake app. *Note: after install you will need to go into the wp database and change your paths to include webroot/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking to bin Cake, and do the site in wordpress using a plugin, then yes thats possible but be very careful.  Wordpress plugins can be great* if they perfectly match your requirements, but if they don't, you hit "the wall" - the unmagical place where you are no longer able to make changes to your app.

*Wordpress plugins can also be terrible.  Be very careful who made it.

One good one is: http://pippinsplugins.com/tag/restrict-content-pro/

Pippin makes great plugins & if this matches your requirements now & in the future go for it.  If you need the flexibility to make any changes your business needs, stick with cake.

In terms of migrating your data  - you would have to write something bespoke to extract the data from the cake app - maybe in the WP xml format to do that.